# Need help with my title

Tags: title

I'm negotiating a new job and need some advice on titles. I'm normally a senior-level software engineer (about 9 years exp), but this new role will be non-coding. The company doesn't have an engineering group, but instead contracts out heavily. They want me to be the technical go-between... software requirements generation, design reviews, and regulatory stuff (medical device).

Basically, very close to the software, but not writing code. What would you call this?

Comment: You can try using the following term which is used very loosely to describe what you are looking for: Specialist: As the primary assignment, performs a specific quality related function within the company’s quality program. Examples include management representative, statistician, and testing expert. Has received direct training or has been performing the activity for a number of years. Shows a high degree of skill performing that specific activity.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/416/is-there-a-title-for-that) for a discussion on questions like this.

Comment: A Business or Systems Analyst

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of possible ways I'd describe this role:

Business analyst - If you are getting into the domain knowledge of software and handling the translation back and forth with requirements and some basic design.

Solution architect - This would be the more technical title I could see.  This is the high level planning and overall structure person that lets others handle the technical details.

Comment: They were the two titles that leapt to my mind when I read the question, also.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar role as a member of a team.  I was a computer engineer between a team of mechanical engineers and electrical engineers.

I had to speak both languages, essentially, knowing what a fifth wheel was and what a zener diode was.

This was a research position, so my actual title was Research Assistant, but when people asked what I did (more than just being a research assistant), I considered myself a technical engineering liaison.

This puts an emphasis on people skills AND the ability to speak technically.

I would check with the company, as it's likely they have had similar roles in the past.  Your title could be solutions architect as JBKing suggested, or it could be lead developer, or business analyst.

At Microsoft, lead developers tend to take on more architect and management focused roles, so this would not be without precedent.